# Databind Class property with grid Height

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have the following class:

```
public class Height
{
    public GridLength GridHeight = new GridLength(200);
}
```

I want to bind this field to the 1st Rows Height from a grid:

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding Path=GridHeight, Mode=OneWay}"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

I have also declared the DataContext:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = new Height();
    }
```

However there is no interaction at all. I cant see what´s wrong.
Very grateful if someone could explain how to databind a class property to a rows Height property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding **works only with Properties not with fields**, and updates only if you implement Inotifypropertychanged interface

so here whenever you update the value on the GridHeight the grid updates its value automatically

```
public class Height:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    GridLength _gridheight = new GridLength(200);
    public GridLength GridHeight
            {
                    get{
                            return _gridheight;
                       }

                    set{
                            if(_gridheight==value)
                               return;

                            _gridheight=value;
                            NotifyPropertyChanged("GridHeight")
                        }

         }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make `GridHeight` a property, not a field.

You may also want to implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the `Height` class if you want it to update.

```
public class Height
{
    public Height() 
    {
        this.GridHeight = new GridLength(200);
    }

    // Needs to be a property for data binding
    public GridLength GridHeight { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for mentioning the INotifyPropertyChanged!